I'm getting a 403 response from the Python API Library
I have all the permissions and I still get a 403 error
{'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'Forbidden: possibly, the used client/token does not ' 'have enough scopes', 'status': 403}, 'server_time': 1729110263} 
I receive all the tokens and API keys properly.

Judging by the response, you probably send a request to the decommissioned API, instead of using GraphQL.
Please, check the documentation or contact Support Team
